# Maven Dependency showing up as a folder inside Maven Dependencies folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have 2 projects. Both are Maven based Java projects. Project2 has Project1 as a dependency in it's pom.xml file, however when I look inside the Maven Dependencies folder in eclipse, I notice that Project1 shows up as a folder and not a jar. Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 15):

m2eclipse offers the feature of resolving dependencies in the workspace. This can be disabled in the Maven popup menu on the project.

```
Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution
```

Answer (score 6):

Go To Maven Dependencies -> Properties -> Maven Project Settings -> disable Resolve dependencies from Workspace Projects